# Problem with UIBezierPath containsPoint when rotating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I got a UIView which contains a UIBezierPath. (this path is used to draw a shape in drawRect:).

Image of my setup (Blue is the UIView with the drawn shape, Red is the shape of the UIBezierPath (found by trial-error)).
[image: First Image]

Everything works fine!

but when i rotate the UIView the path does not rotate (but it draws correctly):
[image: Second Image]

As you can see it is no longer updated and in sync with the UIView.

I use CGAffineTransformMakeRotation to rotate the UIView so i thought that i could do the same transformation on the UIBezierPath ([UIBezierPath applyTransform]), but this makes the beziepath disappear (i was not able to find it in the view). still drawing correctly…

any ideas?

best regards
Kristian

Answer (score 1):

Could you try by creating a Container view (UIView) and use it as the parent view for both of your shapes (UIView & UIBezierPath).

Then Apply the Rotation/Animation on only Container View (Parent view).

Comment: so you suggest using a UIView and inside of that view add a subview (which is my UIView containing the UIBezierpath)?

Comment: I tried it, but i still got the same result as in the second image :(